# Alexa Skill: Intent Name cannot be empty

Tags: android-intent, schema, alexa-skills-kit

I just tried to develop my first alexa skill with this simple code, but unfortunately it always shows me that the intent name cannot be empty. Whats wrong here? It is a parse error on line 5, but why?

```
{
"intents": [
  {
  "intent": "HelloIntent",
  "slots" : [
    (
        "name" : "FirstName",
        "type" : "GUEST_NAMES"
    )
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The round brackets are invalid chars you need to type with the JSON syntax. Just delete them and it should be fine. An array initialised with `[` and closed with `]`.

Do it this way:

```
"slots" : [
    "name" : "FirstName",
    "type" : "GUEST_NAMES"
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
{
"intents": [
  {
  "intent": "HelloIntent",
  "slots" : [
        "name" : "FirstName",
        "type" : "GUEST_NAMES"
  ]
}
```